# Python - 'if name in dict:' OR 'try:/except:'

Tags: python

I'm writing some OO Python and I would like to know which of these methods is more pythonic, or which is generally better, or faster. This is an accessor for an attribute which is a dictionary.

Method 1: `if/else`

```
def GetSlot(self, slot_name):
    if slot_name in self.Slots:
        return self.Slots[slot_name]
    else:
        return None
```

Method 2: `try/except`

```
def GetSlot(self, slot_name):
    try:
        return self.Slots[slot_name]
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

I understand that using `try/except` is better use of duck typing, but will this make a positive impact on performance?

Comment: It's 'Look Before You Leap' LBYL vs 'Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission' EAFP. The latter is probably more Pythonic, but performance doesn't come into it until you apply this to a real problem and start profiling. And that's the problem with this question: the code is two snippets. We don't do snippets. Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Oh yes you're right, sorry. I didn't read the posting rules. I suppose that's why code review exists and this isn't just stack overflow 2. Should I move/remove this question, or leave it as it already has an answer? If it's gonna get struck down by mods I may as well save them the trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It depends.

Mostly, it depends on whether it'll generally be in the dictionary or not. If it's nearly always in the dictionary, then the try/except method would win out, while if it's in there as often as not, then checking would be somewhat faster.

However, python already anticipated your need. There's a better option:

```py
def GetSlot(self, slot_name):
    return self.Slots.get(slot_name)
```

All mappings support get, which has a default optional argument that defaults to None. This should be the best option. However, that said...

- `GetSlot` is not a PEP8-compliant name. It should be `get_slot`.
- `self.Slots` should probably be `self.slots`.
- NOTE: Since you confirmed in a comment that you are in fact using externally defined names, I think it is best practice to follow those names as well as their naming conventions when appropriate.
- This should probably not be a method at all. In python, accessor functions are somewhat frowned upon. If you really need to do something like this, use [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work). However, anything wanting to get `slot_name` from `self.Slots` should just use `self.Slots.get(slot_name)`. *Even if you're reaching into the object from outside*. Java and other languages that advocate getter/setter methods do so because it later allows you to change how it is gotten, but Python is better and doesn't require workarounds like this to influence how you access a variable. [Read more here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36943813/4331885)

#### A note on Python getters and setters

Python [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3.7/howto/descriptor.html) are a powerful tool. It's not actually an object, it's a protocol of how python retrieves variables when they're used as object attributes. The classic example is python's `property`, but in truth methods on a class are also descriptors. An object implements this protocol by having `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__` methods on it. Not all are required for every type of descriptors - please follow the link for in-depth classification and usages.

What this all means in practice is that python objects can change how they are retrieved. This is impossible in languages like Java, which can cause engineering issues.

Let's first figure out why people use getters and setters in Java, because the reasons they have are quite important.

So I have a class with an attribute that I want to expose to the public for usage.

(NOTE: Java users please don't take offense. I'm writing just Python here since I've honestly never used Java. All my knowledge of it is second-hand at best.)

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.distance_to_orgin = pythagoras(x, y)
# Later...
instance = Point(a, b)
instance.distance_to_orgin
```

Now, everyone can access it. So I publish my library, and everyone's code works fine.

But then, I get a better idea - every point already knows it's x and y, so I can always calculate the distance_to_orgin if I need it.

In Java, I now have a problem. Because to calculate something on retrieval, I NEED a function - but everyone accesses it by attribute access. I cannot make this change in a backwards compatible manner. So, programmers learn to make getter and setter methods. Compare to before:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.distance_to_orgin = pythagoras(x, y)

    def get_distance_to_orgin(self):
        return self.distance_to_orgin


# Later...
instance = Point(a, b)
instance.get_distance_to_orgin()
```

Now, if I want to change how it works, I can just write a different get_distance_to_orgin method and I can make the change - fully backwards compatible!

So why isn't this a problem in Python?

Because we have descriptors. In 99.9% of cases, the builtin property() does everything you want. I can just amend my class definition like this:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        # self._distance_to_orgin = pythagoras(x, y) No longer needed

    @property
    def distance_to_orgin(self):
        return pythagoras(self.x, self.y)

# Later...
instance = Point(a, b)
instance.distance_to_orgin
```

And the external usage is *exactly* the same as it was at the very start, back when we were building a class in a naive way!

So that is why getters and setters are important for many languages, but why we don't need them in Python.

Comment: Not a crappy answer, this is exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you :) I appreciate your other comments, but unfortunately I'm making a replacement for a module that's already in place, so I need to copy their naming for my code to slot in without changing anything other than the import statement :// The module I'm replacing/emulating is PyCLIPS.

Comment: A question related to your second point - Is using setter methods also frowned upon? In my case each `Slot` may or may not have strict allowed values. Each `Slot` object has an attribute `AllowedValues` which is a list that may be empty.

Comment: That explanation about getter/setters is a bit to long for a comment, I'll edit it in. But if you're building on/wrapping a library with another style, then keeping that style is IMO better than twisting yourself to obey PEP8.

Comment: I see now! I don't think I've ever found a reason for using descriptors justified that clearly before, thank you :) And I suppose I could always define `SetSlot(self, name, value)` to call this property if I want both methods available.

Comment: Since there's nothing in your question about setters: I'd just use `self.Slots[slot_name] = value`, and try/except around where you use it. No real need for a setter either. And if you don't like exceptions, just check from outside: `if value in self.Slots[slot_name].AllowedValues: self.Slots[slot_name] = value`

Comment: In the future, please refrain from answering off-topic questions.

Comment: @Mast I thought this one was ok, but I guess I was wrong then. I'll keep an eye out.